# How to emit multiple parameter in vue-quill editor?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-quill-editor

I am using vue-quill editor and trying to use it with a custom component. Here is my code.

#### WysiwygInput.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="my-3">
    <quill-editor
      :options="{
        placeholder: placeholder,
      }"
      v-on:change="($event) => $emit('change', $event.text)"
    ></quill-editor>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### Create.vue

```
<wysiwyg-input @change="setField" placeholder="Post Content" />
```

I want to access the quill-editor value with an extra parameter, something like this.

```
<wysiwyg-input @change="setField($event.text, 'content')" placeholder="Post Content" />
```

So what to change on WysiwygInput.vue ? Thanks is advance.

**Codesandbox link:** https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-benz-w8wgu?file=/src/FormFields.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could emit many params using `$emit` method :

```
 v-on:change="($event) => $emit('change', $event.text,param2,param3)"
```

and in parent component add the handler like :

```
<wysiwyg-input @change="setField" placeholder="Post Content" />

...
setField(text,param2,param3){
 ...
}
```

if you want to add parameter to the emitted event handler in parent component you should add inline handler like :

```
<wysiwyg-input @change="(text)=>setField(text, 'content')" placeholder="Post Content" />
```

Comment: @Brahim I am not sure how to send second argument on the @change="setField" function. the second argument will be always dynamic. For example, 'content', 'title' etc.
Please see the codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-benz-w8wgu?file=/src/FormFields.vue

Comment: the dynamic param from where do you want to send it ? from parent or child component?

Comment: from the parent Component component.

Comment: please consider this one as example 
<input
        type="text"
        @input="setField($event.target.value, 'title')"
      />